# How to unset on nested array in PHP using a posted key?

Tags: php, arrays, debugging, nested, unset

I'm working on a bookmark manager and I am currently implementing a feature to remove a certain category. The category is posted via AJAX and is in string format. The bookmarks array is a nested array that looks like this:

```
$currentBookmarks = array("Category A" => array(),
                    "Category B" => array());
```

Here is part of my code in which I want to unset/delete a category:

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'deleteCategory') {

        // Get category title -- Category B (checked)
        $categoryToDelete = $_POST['category'];

        // Get current bookmarks
        $currentBookmarks = $_SESSION['bookmarks'];

        print_r("Bookmarks array we got from the session: <BR>");
        var_dump($currentBookmarks);

        // Remove bookmark category
        unset($currentBookmarks[$categoryToDelete]);

        print_r("After unsetting the category that we want to delete: <BR>");
        var_dump($currentBookmarks);

        // Set bookmarks back to session
        $_SESSION['bookmarks'] = $currentBookmarks;
```

This code results in the following dumps:

> Bookmarks array we got from the session: 
>  
>   array(2) { ["Category A"]=> array(0) { } ["Category B"]=> array(0) { } }
>
> Bookmarks array after unsetting the category that we want to delete: 
>   array(2) { ["Category A"]=> array(0) { } ["Category B"]=> array(0) { } }

As you can see the before/after are exactly the same.
I tried more ways to unset the category but they all don't seem to work.

Would really appreciate some help here! I'm kinda breaking my head over this.

Thanks in advance,

Nathan

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['category']);` contain?

Comment: Oh that's weird! I just checked and it contains the following: string(2) "Category B ". Notice the space? I really don't know how it got there but that's probably the problem. Do you have any idea how it could get there?

Comment: Oh man! I accidently put a space in my dynamically generated HTML code when I was trying to organize and 'beautify' my code... It's all working now! Thank you for guiding me in the good direction.